# SQL query to sum total turnover for countries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can someone explain how can i get the sum turnover for each country based on this query?

```
SELECT ZipCodes.Country AS country, (LineItem.price*LineItem.quantity) as turnover
FROM LineItem
INNER JOIN [Order] ON [Order].id = LineItem.order_id
INNER JOIN Party ON Party.id = [Order].party_id
INNER JOIN ZipCodes ON ZipCodes.id = Party.party_zip_code_id
GROUP BY ZipCodes.Country
```

I am getting:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Column 'LineItem.price' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
>
> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Column 'LineItem.quantity' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: did you mean SUM(LineItem.price*LineItem.quantity) as turnover

Comment: add an aggregate function to your expression (as @bummi suggests), or remove the `group by`

Comment: no comment. Im a noob. thanx

Comment: "add sum(turn over)  " in select list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add the `sum` to your query:

```
SELECT 
    ZipCodes.Country AS country, 
    sum(LineItem.price*LineItem.quantity) as turnover -- Add here the sum
FROM 
    LineItem
    INNER JOIN [Order] ON [Order].id = LineItem.order_id
    INNER JOIN Party ON Party.id = [Order].party_id
    INNER JOIN ZipCodes ON ZipCodes.id = Party.party_zip_code_id
GROUP BY 
    ZipCodes.Country
```

Comment: we all have suffered something like this once. happy to help